# Trying to grab HTML-code from local file to my email sender

Tags: python, html, pandas, email, smtplib

I have a code which loads list of email adresses into my email sender, and usually I send it with an HTML-code and plain text (Multipart) within the code, but I would like to grab the HTML code from a .txt / .html-file instead locally.

This way I can organize it better and there will be less code.

I am trying the pd.read_html here, just like pd.read_excel works for the lists I'm uploading, but I can't get it to work.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import time

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib

email_list = pd.read_excel('/home/seniori/Documents/Folder/test.xlsx')
template = pd.read_html('/home/seniori/Documents/Folder/test.html')


emails = email_list['EMAIL']

my_list = email_list['EMAIL'].tolist()
print(my_list)
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = "email@example.com"

msg['Subject'] = "Subject"

message = template


message2 = "plain text"
msg.attach(MIMEText(message,'html'))
msg.attach(MIMEText(message2,'plain'))
```

Here is the error:

```
>>> email_list = pd.read_excel('/home/seniori/Documents/Leadlists/UK/test.xlsx')
>>> template = pd.read_html('/home/seniori/Documents/Leadlists/UK/test.html')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/seniori/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 1085, in read_html
    return _parse(
  File "/home/seniori/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 915, in _parse
    raise retained
  File "/home/seniori/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 895, in _parse
    tables = p.parse_tables()
  File "/home/seniori/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 213, in parse_tables
    tables = self._parse_tables(self._build_doc(), self.match, self.attrs)
  File "/home/seniori/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 545, in _parse_tables
    raise ValueError("No tables found")
ValueError: No tables found
```

Would really appreciate some help on this. Thank in advance!

Comment: Is there a table in the HTML file? This how pandas is expecting a table to be define in HTML: "This function searches for <table> elements and only for <tr> and <th> rows and <td> elements within each <tr> or <th> element in the table." -- From the pandas API documentation

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the comments, `read_html` is not for reading arbitrary HTML. You use it to load tables that are stored in HTML format. I think you need something along these lines:

```py
import pandas
import smtplib

from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

# I don't have your files, but this should work
# email_list = pandas.read_excel('/home/seniori/Documents/Folder/test.xlsx')
# with open('/home/seniori/Documents/Folder/test.html', "r") as template_file:
#     template = template_file.read()

# Assuming the content of the files looks something like this:
email_list = pandas.DataFrame([
    {
        "EMAIL": "a@b.com",
        "NAME": "Person A"
    },
    {
        "EMAIL": "c@d.com",
        "NAME": "Person C"
    }
])

html_template = """
<div>
<p>Dear {NAME},</p>
<p>Bla <b>bla</b>.</p>
<p>Kind regards,</p>
<p><i>{ME}</i></p>
</div>
"""

text_template = """
Dear {NAME},
Bla bla.
Kind regards,
{ME}
"""


# Create an SMTP server to send the emails
# smtp_server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')


# Loop the people in your email_list
for _, to in email_list.iterrows():
    print(to)

    # Create a new message
    message = MIMEMultipart()

    # Set the metadata of the message
    message["Subject"] = "My subject here"
    message["From"] = "email@example.com"
    message["To"] = to["EMAIL"]

    # Fill the templates with the parameters
    content_html = html_template.format(**to.to_dict(), **{"ME": "garymaker"})
    content_plain = text_template.format(**to.to_dict(), **{"ME": "garymaker"})

    message.attach(MIMEText(content_html, "html"))
    message.attach(MIMEText(content_plain, "plain"))

    # Send the message
    # smtp_server.send_message(message)
    print(message)


# Stop the SMTP server
# smtp_server.quit()
```

Output:

```py
EMAIL     a@b.com
NAME     Person A
Name: 0, dtype: object
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============1933032015397261065=="
MIME-Version: 1.0
Subject: My subject here
From: email@example.com
To: a@b.com

--===============1933032015397261065==
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


<div>
<p>Dear Person A,</p>
<p>Bla <b>bla</b>.</p>
<p>Kind regards,</p>
<p><i>garymaker</i></p>
</div>

--===============1933032015397261065==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


Dear Person A,
Bla bla.
Kind regards,
garymaker

--===============1933032015397261065==--

EMAIL     c@d.com
NAME     Person C
Name: 1, dtype: object
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============3497697477590467437=="
MIME-Version: 1.0
Subject: My subject here
From: email@example.com
To: c@d.com

--===============3497697477590467437==
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


<div>
<p>Dear Person C,</p>
<p>Bla <b>bla</b>.</p>
<p>Kind regards,</p>
<p><i>garymaker</i></p>
</div>

--===============3497697477590467437==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


Dear Person C,
Bla bla.
Kind regards,
garymaker

--===============3497697477590467437==--
```

NOTE: I don't have and SMTP server so I've commented out those lines.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding the following:

```
import urllib.request

template = urllib.request.urlopen('file:///home/siri/Folder/test.html').read()

message = template

msg.attach(MIMEText(message,'html', 'utf-8'))
```

These are what was added to the code. As far as I understand it (correct me if I'm wrong) the urllib.request-module makes it able to read a UTF-8 encoded .HTML-file when defining it.